# preview doesn’t reflect actual appearance of post when links are on one line seperated by <br> tags

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, markdown-preview

In my answer at [Summing a binomial series that arose while counting functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4883061), I listed some related questions like this:

```
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1340297<br>https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4307652<br>https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1006752<br>https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2714039<br>[The number of permutations of given order][4]
```

The preview correctly showed the titles of the questions, but when I submitted the answer, the result was this:

[image]

Except for the first and last, the links appear as raw, unclickable URLs rather than being replaced by links with the title of the questions. I edited and put each link and each `<br>` tag on a separate line like this

```
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1340297
<br>
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4307652
<br>
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1006752
<br>
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2714039
<br>
[The number of permutations of given order][4]
```

and now the links display correctly.

I don’t mind so much whether the form on one line works or not, but in either case it would be good if the preview showed the final result.